# Posting value to web service

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, asmx

I understand how to post a value back to a standard asp.net page and how to then use that value at the serverside:

```
Request.Form("id_of_posted_value_goes_here")
```

How do I do the same in a webservice (asmx)?

I can't use the line above because it says:

`Name 'Request' is not declared.`

Comment: Why would you need such thing in an *asp.NET* web service? You just have to put `[WebMethod]` attribute on your functions and your done...

Comment: I should have written that I am still very new to web services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An asmx web service uses [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). So you don't simply POST independent values to a SOAP service as you do with a normal ASPX web page. You must respect the standard. So in order to invoke an asmx web service a client needs to create a SOAP request wrapping the parameters in conformance to the exposed WSDL. If you are using Visual Studio you could use the `Add Service Reference` dialog in order to generate a strongly typed client in order to invoke the service.